# Ajax DataTables not showing, and gives back an error instead

Tags: ajax, datatables, laravel-5.4

So I have this problem with an Ajax DataTable, when I load the page it gives this error : [image: Error]

and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's supposed to show a table with the data that's stored in the database, and to each line add a "view", "edit", "delete" buttons. And the delete button does soft deletes.

Here's the code for my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Supplier;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\StoreSuppliersRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\UpdateSuppliersRequest;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use DB;
class SuppliersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of Group.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('supplier_access')) {
            return abort(401);
        }


    $user = \Auth::user();

    if (request()->ajax()) {
        $query = Supplier::query();



          if (\Auth::getUser()->role_id==1) {

          $q = Supplier::select(['name','anschrift']);
         }

        $template = 'actionsTemplate';
        if(request('show_deleted') == 1) {

    if (! Gate::allows('supplier_delete')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
            $q->onlyTrashed();
            $template = 'restoreTemplate';
        }
        $table = DataTables::of($q)->make(true);

        $table->setRowAttr([
            'data-entry-id' => '{{$id}}',
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('massDelete', '&nbsp;');
        $table->addColumn('actions', '&nbsp;');
        $table->editColumn('actions', function ($row) use ($template) {
            $gateKey  = 'supplier_';
            $routeKey = 'admin.suppliers';

            return view($template, compact('row', 'gateKey', 'routeKey'));
        });
        $table->editColumn('Name', function ($row) {
            return $row->Name ? $row->Name : '';
        });
        $table->editColumn('anschrift', function ($row) {
            return $row->anschrift ? $row->anschrift : '';
        });


        return $table->make(true);
    }

    return view('admin.suppliers.index');
}
```

this the HTML of where the table is supposed to be:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        @lang('quickadmin.qa_list')
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ajaxTable @can('supplier_delete') @if ( request('show_deleted') != 1 ) dt-select @endif @endcan">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @can('supplier_delete')
                        @if ( request('show_deleted') != 1 )<th style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all" /></th>@endif
                    @endcan

                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Anschrift</th>
                    <!-- <th>Adminsnachname</th> -->
                    @if( request('show_deleted') == 1 )
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    @else
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    @endif
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript code that handles it:

```
<script>
    @can('supplier_delete')
        @if ( request('show_deleted') != 1 ) window.route_mass_crud_entries_destroy = '{{ route('admin.suppliers.mass_destroy') }}'; @endif
    @endcan
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.dtDefaultOptions.ajax = '{!! route('admin.suppliers.index') !!}?show_deleted={{ request('show_deleted') }}';
        window.dtDefaultOptions.columns = [
            @can('supplier_delete')
            @if ( request('show_deleted') != 1 )
                {data: 'massDelete', name: 'id', searchable: false, sortable: false},
            @endif
            @endcan
            {data: 'Name', name: 'Name'},
            {data: 'anschrift', name: 'anschrift'},
            // {data: 'admin.lastname', lastname: 'admin.lastname'},
            {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', searchable: false, sortable: false}
        ];
        processAjaxTables();
    });
</script>
```

processAjaxTables:

```
function processAjaxTables() {
$('.ajaxTable').each(function () {
    window.dtDefaultOptions.processing = true;
    window.dtDefaultOptions.serverSide = true;
    if ($(this).hasClass('dt-select')) {
        window.dtDefaultOptions.select = {
            style: 'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        };

        window.dtDefaultOptions.columnDefs.push({
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets: 0
        });
    }
    $(this).DataTable(window.dtDefaultOptions);
    if (typeof window.route_mass_crud_entries_destroy != 'undefined') {
        $(this).siblings('.actions').html('<a href="' + window.route_mass_crud_entries_destroy + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger js-delete-selected" style="margin-top:0.755em;margin-left: 20px;">'+window.deleteButtonTrans+'</a>');
    }
});
```

}

Until now I still haven't figured out what I did wrong

Comment: How does `processAjaxTables()` look like''?

Comment: The DataTables manual gives a good description of how to diagnose the issue.  You're ajax call is not returning 200 (ok) response.   Use the dev tools in the browser to see what is coming back.  https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Comment: @davidkonrad I edited the post, I've added the code of the `processAjaxTables()` function